# Symfony Sonata Admin - Security issue with Role and on_top

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

i got a problem with security and menu.

I have a menu point "Besuchsmanagement" set on_top: true
Now i have roles for this.

My problem is, that the on_top always be shown, if role is granted or not.

ROLES:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN_VISIT_READER:
      - ROLE_ADMIN_VISIT_LIST
      - ROLE_ADMIN_VISIT_VIEW
    ROLE_ADMIN_VISIT_CREATOR:
      - ROLE_ADMIN_VISIT_READER
      - ROLE_ADMIN_VISIT_CREATE
      - ROLE_ADMIN_VISIT_EDIT
    ROLE_ADMIN_VISIT_ADMIN:
      - ROLE_ADMIN_VISIT_ALL 
    ROLE_USER:
      - ROLE_ADMIN_VISIT_ADMIN
```

services.yml

```
 admin.visit:
      class: ifabrik\VisitBundle\Admin\VisitAdmin
      arguments: [~, ifabrik\VisitBundle\Entity\Visit, ~]
      tags:
          - { name: sonata.admin, group: Besuchsmanagement, manager_type: orm, on_top: true, icon: '<i class="fa fa-map-signs" aria-hidden="true"></i>' }
```

When i remove on_top - then roles are correct.

Comment: Can you show your menu config ?

Comment: Standard Sonata :)

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing on_top in the service definition you should be configuring your admin menu in your app/config.yml.

Here is an example :

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            Customers Relationship Management:
            label: libio.menu_label.crm
            icon:  '<i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>'
            on_top: true
            roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
            items:
                - route: admin_librinfo_crm_organism_list
                  label: libio.menu_label.organisms_list
```

As you can see you can specify the roles to wich the menu entry will be shown.

To find out the route execute the command

```
app/console (bin/console on sf3) debug:router
```

Comment: Hi and thank you Mawcel :) - i dont want to configure the roles on the menu, only with roles. Everything works fine - but not on_top.